# Why does it crash?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

Mr. Little Z is looking at a piece of paper and unsuccessfully trying to find the square root of a number written on the paper.

Help Mr. Little Z find the number B which is the square root of BIG number A. The number A has 1000 digits at most and the square root of A will always be an integer.

INPUT:
The first line of the standard input contains the number 0

OUTPUT:
To the standard output write number M, where M represents the length of number B (where B is the square-root of the number A) and in the next M lines write the digits of the number B (from the most significant digit to the least significant).

Input: 
3 
6 
2 
5

Output: 
2 
2 
5

Explanation: 
The number written on the paper was 625, and its square-root is 25.

My Code :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int n,m,k,i; 
    int niza[1001]; 

    cin>>m; 
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) 
    cin>>niza[i]; 

    niza[i]=k; 
    cout<<sqrt(k); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What value are you inputting when you run the program?

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to help future visitors to the site. Too localized.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is because you never set `k`, and the random value it contains at the start of the program is negative, so `sqrt(k)` crashes. Also, if `m` is entered as greater than `1000`, you will go outside the array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will crash at: `niza[i] = k` because `i` is past the end of the array.

`k` is not initialized.  You are outputting the square root of an uninitialized variable.

Like @Vilx- said, you will have to check the value of `m` before your loop.

Also, the `sqrt` function does not work on an array of numbers, so you will have to come up with a different method to calculate square root based on digits.

You will need to check the status of `cin` after `cin >> m` and `cin >> niza[i]`.  Users can and will enter anything, such as letters, which cause failure when a number is expected.

Also, try putting spaces between operators and function names.  They don't add anything to the size or speed of an executable, but make reading and maintenance easier.